# Yup validation of object with one of the values as array of itself, and another one with dynamic key

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, yup

I have objects with the following interface:

```
interface AttributeValue {
  L?: AttributeValue[] | undefined;
  M?: { [id: string]: AttributeValue } | undefined;
}
```

is it possible to use Yup to validate them and how to write the schema?